# RunCloud deployment: Your local changes to the following files (package-locked.json) would be overwritten by merge

Tags: git

Each time I deploy a `develop` branch I get the following issue:

```
From github.com:foo/bar
   75be85b..07d10bb  develop    -> origin/develop
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
    package-lock.json
Please commit your changes or stash them before you merge.
Aborting
```

**My solution (but it's not permanent)**

I ssh into the server and in the root of the project I type:

```
git checkout HEAD -- package-lock.json
```

Then when I deploy again the issue disappears, however problem comes back each time I merge new branch to develop and try to deploy again.

The issue is within my `package-lock.json` or my deployment script? How can I permanently solve this issue?

```
git merge // <- I assume it fails on this line

composer dump-autoload -o
composer install --no-interaction --prefer-dist --optimize-autoloader

php artisan migrate --force
php artisan clear-compiled
php artisan view:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan optimize

npm install
npm run production

php artisan queue:restart
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `npm ci` it **does not** modify package-lock.json while `npm install` **does** modify when get new minor version on modules.

Some info copy from npm help ci

```
In short, the main differences between using npm install and npm ci are:

· The project must have an existing package-lock.json or npm-shrinkwrap.json.

· If dependencies in the package lock do not match those in package.json, 
npm ci will exit with an error, instead of updating the package lock.

· npm ci can only install entire projects at a time: 
individual dependencies cannot be added with this command.

· If a node_modules is already present, it will be automatically 
removed before npm ci begins its install.

· It will never write to package.json or any of the package-locks: 
installs are essentially frozen.
```